# meaning of "throughout one's account"

Tags: meaning

I've encountered this sentence in a book but I wasn't able to understand what "throughout their accounts" means. Could anyone help me understand the meaning of this statement, please?

"Throughout their accounts, they present with great perfection the struggles of working in an environment."

Thank you.

Comment: You might find [Merriam-Webster's definition #7 of "account" as a noun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/account) to be an aid to understanding.

Comment: I suspect your text was written by a non-native speaker. The words **present with great perfection** look decidedly non-idiomatic to me, and I can't find that exact sequence anywhere in either Google Books or through a Google Internet search. But the sequence **Throughout their accounts** is just "ordinary English" for ***consistently** [in their descriptions / reports / accounts]*.

Answer (score 2):

An "account" in this context is "a report or description of an event or experience". Sometimes multiple accounts, from different people's individual perspectives, are collected together to give a broader picture of an event.

> Throughout their accounts, they present with great perfection the struggles of working in an environment.

Whoever "they" are in your quote, it sounds like multiple persons gave accounts, and "throughout" them all (meaning many times at various points in the text) they all made the same point.